# Display Apache JMeter logs, in Grafana using the Logs Panel and InfluxDB as data source

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb

Objective : To Use Grafana log panel to display Apache JMeter Logs for an execution, using InfluxDB Backend Listener.

- apache-jmeter-5.5
- influxdb-1.8.10-1
- grafana-8.5.0

I am using InfluxDBBackendListenerClient for my JMeter tests and grafana to display the the test metrics data into the dashboard.

I want to use the Grafana Logs Panel, to fetch Apache-Jmeter Execution Data,
I had accomplished this couple of years back and the log panel use to look like the below image:
[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have that dashboard and want to integrate the logs to my current dashboard.My Current logs dashboard looks like this below:

[image]

Influx Query: I have used the below mentioned influx query, I know something is wrong with the query.

[image]

I would really appreciate is anyone can help me resolve this query and aid me to get a dashboard in similar format as the first image,

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's Backend listener doesn't send Apache JMeter logs, here is the [list of the metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) which are supported as of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

```
15.1.1 Thread/Virtual Users metrics

Thread metrics are the following:

<rootMetricsPrefix>test.minAT
    Min active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.maxAT
    Max active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.meanAT
    Mean active threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.startedT
    Started threads
<rootMetricsPrefix>test.endedT
    Finished threads

 15.1.2 Response times metrics

Response related metrics are the following:

<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.count
    Number of successful responses for sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.h.count
    Server hits per seconds, this metric cumulates Sample Result and Sub results (if using Transaction Controller, "Generate parent sampler" should be unchecked)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.min
    Min response time for successful responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.max
    Max response time for successful responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.avg
    Average response time for successful responses of sampler name.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for successful responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.count
    Number of failed responses for sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.min
    Min response time for failed responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.max
    Max response time for failed responses of sampler name
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.avg
    Average response time for failed responses of sampler name.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for failed responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value.
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.count
    Number of responses for sampler name (sum of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.sb.bytes
    Sent Bytes
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.rb.bytes
    Received Bytes
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.min
    Min response time for responses of sampler name (min of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.max
    Max response time for responses of sampler name (max of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.avg
    Average response time for responses of sampler name (avg of ok.count and ko.count)
<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.a.pct<percentileValue>
    Percentile computed for responses of sampler name. There will be one metric for each calculated value. (calculated on the totals for OK and failed samples)
```

In order to be able to see JMeter log in Grafana you need to add it somehow to InfluxDB, I can think of the following options:

1. Periodically read it using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and sending to [InfluxDB HTTP endpoint](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/api/) using "normal" JMeter [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
2. Come up with your own implementation of the [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) which will be sending log file entries along with other metrics